# Get a Cell value as value for function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to create a google sheet script that copy a list into another table(Name of new Table is in Cell D5). The copying does work but i must type the tablename manual in the script. The table name must be in the code at the point "[here]".

I created a variable that have the value "D5". After that he doesn´t found the table.

```
function alleDaten() {

  var sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktueller_Fall");

var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("[here]");

  sheet1.getRange(10, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1));
}
```

Comment: Try using [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompttitle-prompt-buttons)

Comment: That work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function alleDaten() {
  var sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktueller_Fall");
```

Insert Prompt Here:

```
  var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("[here]");//get the sheetname from the prompt response
  sheet1.getRange(10, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1));
}
```

Like this:

```
function CopyDataToAnotherSheet() {
  var sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Provide Sheet Name", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(resp.getResponseText());
    sheet1.getRange(10, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1));
  }
}
```